# Exporting EC_POINT using point2hex in ASN1.DER and recreate with Java as an X.509

Tags: c++, openssl, x509, ecdsa, asn.1

I am generating ECDSA Prime256 keypair using OpenSSL with C++ and trying to import the hex version of the public key using Java. I pass the byte array I obtain from C++ to the following function in java which expects the byte array to be in an X.509 encoded format.

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(byte[] pk) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pk);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(Constant.KEY_FACTORY_TYPE);
    PublicKey pub = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    return pub;
}
```

I create an elliptic curve key pair using the following function which retuns an `EC_KEY*`

```
EC_KEY* generate_keypair() {
    EC_KEY *eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_GROUP *ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ecgroup);
    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eckey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
    int kpGenerationStatus = EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
    if (kpGenerationStatus) {
        return eckey;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Given the keypair returned by the function above, I want to export the public key to an ASN1.DER format which can be imported using the java method above.

I convert the public key which is of type `EC_POINT*` to its hex form using `EC_POINT_point2hex()` by doing the following:

```
EC_GROUP *ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
EC_KEY *keypair = generate_keypair();
char *result = NULL;
BN_CTX *ctx;
ctx = BN_CTX_new();
const EC_POINT *pub = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(keypair);
result = EC_POINT_point2hex(ecgroup, pub, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, ctx);
printf("%s\n", result);
```

Which return the following:
`04F588CD1D7103A993D47E53D58C3F40BE8F570604CF2EA01A7657C1423EB19C51BC379F0BEE1FAA60BB9A07DE73EA9BEF7709C1C6429D4051B44F73A458FFB80D`

When I inspect this with the [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) I see a message which says `Length over 48 bits not supported at position 1` and trying to import it using the java method I receive an error as follows:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): Should use short form for length
```

Is there something I am missing while exporting the public key from EC_POINT* to a X.509 Encoded hex string that I can import for validating any signatures?

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the incorrect direction as you want ASN1 base64 value.

[EC_POINT_point2hex](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EC_POINT_point2hex.html) is converting the internal public key value to hex.  It's not in ASN1 format.

You can produce what you want from the command line like so:

1. Generate EC private key:
   openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
2. Extra public key in DER(ASN1) format:
   openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -outform der -out public.cer
3. Convert to base64
   openssl base64 -in .\public.cer

If you take that output and paste it into ASN.1 decoder link it works fine.

Now to turn this into code, you have the EC key generation, but what you want is the steps to:

1. Generate ASN1 formatted public key
2. Convert it to base64

To generate the ASN1 formatted public key you want to use the [i2d_EC_PUBKEY](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/i2d_EC_PUBKEY.html) set of methods and then convert to base64 using [BIO_f_base64](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BIO_f_base64.html) filter.

So here is an example problem that when I copy the output to ASN.1 decoder link it works fine.

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

EC_KEY* generate_keypair() {
    EC_KEY *eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_GROUP *ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ecgroup);
    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eckey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
    int kpGenerationStatus = EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
    if (kpGenerationStatus) {
        return eckey;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    EC_GROUP *ecgroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    EC_KEY *keypair = generate_keypair();
    BIO* out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO* b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_push(b64, out);

    i2d_EC_PUBKEY_bio(b64, keypair);

    BIO_flush(b64);


    // do what you want this the output in out memory BIO

    char* p;
    long length = BIO_get_mem_data(out, &p);

    // ensure null terminated but copying the buffer into a string to output...
    puts(std::string(p, length).c_str());

    BIO_free_all(out);
}
```

I can't complete on the Java side, but if it works with the manual openssl generated base64 string then it will work with the sample application.